# Dead laptop batteries

Tags: batteries

I disassembled a dead laptop battery and found 6 AA size batteries interconnected. 5 of them still give 1.2V on meter.

If I replace the defective one would the pack be usable again and would it keep charge?[image]

Comment: I'm pretty sure these are *not* AA-sized. The printing on one of them even specifies they're 18650.

Comment: Questions on the repair of consumer electronics, appliances, or other devices must involve specific troubleshooting steps and demonstrate a good understanding of the underlying design of the device being repaired.

Answer (score 6):

I am answering here because others might look up the subject.

Mixing old and new batteries is false economy. You are likely to find one of the remaining 5 batteries to fail soon.

The phrase "throwing good money after bad" is very much applicable here.

Answer (score 3):

They're not AAs, they're 18650 Lithium-Ion batteries, nominal voltage 3.6V.

At 1.2V your batteries have been [over-discharged](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/164103/if-li-ion-battery-is-deeply-discharged-is-it-harmful-for-it-to-remain-in-this-s), they're finished. If you recharge them they won't last.

You can replace all cells with quality 18650 LiIons which aren't that expensive ($6-8 a piece). Purchase from a reputable source (ie, not cheap knockoffs from ebay).

Comment: that, by the way, would amount to 36-48$ for battery replacement. Coincidentally relatively close to the price of aftermarket batteries...

Comment: And, having replaced the cells, you will probably fail to convince the battery controller on that PCB it's good to go again. (Don't ask me how I know...)

Comment: @BrianDrummond That's interesting, well in this case better buy an aftermarket battery...

Comment: This is a 2P-3S battery, with two cells in parallel, three in series. When in parallel, each cell in a pair must be closely matched in terms of internal resistance and overall discharge curve (SOH-state of health), otherwise the mismatched pair will wear off rapidly, resulting in the same dead state. So you would need to buy many more batteries than just two.

Comment: My issue is Airflight companies don’t accept Laptop batteries on board. Can’t order them, I am in Mauritius and trying to find a solution. I have three laptops working permanently on AC adapter.

Comment: [This video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=sRwoYJyjZNo&pp=ygUobGl0aGl1bSBiYXR0ZXJ5IGRlZXAgZGlzY2hhcmdlIGRhbmdlcm91cw%3D%3D) and all comments beneath it seems to suggest the following statement is wrong:

"At 1.2V your batteries have been over-discharged, they're finished."

@bobflux, can you please clarify?